# How does one install py-spy on windows 10?

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I wanted to install py-spy on my Windows 10 (64-bit) machine but I always seem to end up with the following errors:

```
F:\downloads>python --version
Python 3.8.3

F:\downloads>python -m pip install py-spy
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py-spy
ERROR: No matching distribution found for py-spy
```

This is quite strange, since the py-spy website and another post on this forum said that using pip was correct.
Since the pip method didn't work, I decided to try to install the package from the pre-built wheel available on the py-spy website. However, i keep getting the following error message:

```
F:\downloads>pip install py_spy-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: py_spy-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I tried to install py-spy using both cmd.exe and powershell.exe as a regular user and as an administrator with no luck.

Comment: seems that py-spy IS supported for windows [here](https://pypi.org/project/py-spy/0.1.0/) "py-spy supports Python versions 2.3+ and 3.3+ on Linux, OSX and Windows."

Comment: You're directly installing the wheel file (downloaded) and it's for AMD. Are you on an intel machine?

Comment: Is you window a 32bit or a64bit?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 64-bit on an intel-based machine.  So it only works on AMD machines? That's weird.

Comment: Did you try `pip install py-spy` as per https://pypi.org/project/py-spy/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you running in a 32bit OS then it is not supported; check paragraph: [Does py-spy support 32-bit Windows? Integrate with PyPy? Work with USC2 versions of Python2?](https://pypi.org/project/py-spy/)

> Not yet =).
>
> If there are features you’d like to see in py-spy either thumb up the
> appropiate issue or create a new one that describes what functionality
> is missing.

### EDIT

Also try to download Python in 64 Bit!

- [Download](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/python-3.8.3-amd64.exe)
- [Download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

To check which version of Python you are running (32 bit or 64 bit) run Python in any shell, the first line should say:

```
Python 3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Where [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] means 64-bit Python.

Comment: That is the weird thing about it.  I am using Windows Professional 64-bit.  Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: One thing even if you have a 64 bit machine you can still install by mistake the 32 bit Pyhon. I mean I did it in the past, and I actually have 2 version installed.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: if you have Python 32 bit installed and note 64 (hence here the problem) make sure to use the correct versoin of python on the project envirorment or update the windows Path all in once, to test it then run python in a terminal as explain in the answer. As remineder [How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/13903942) Then let us know

Comment: Thanks!  I downloaded the 64-bit version of python and now I can install py-spy.  Have a good one!